# How can I replace a potentiometer with a fixed resistor on a buck converter?

Tags: voltage, power, buck, step-down

I want to use a buck converter which steps down 12 V DC to 5 V constant DV output to power my custom PCB.

I came across a buck converter in market which can do it but there is potentiometer on it which can be adjusted to vary the output voltage.

Below you can see the schematic for the buck converter and where I plan to remove the potentiometer and put fixed resistors to get a 5 V constant output.

[image]

[image]

Can someone help me in how to put fixed resistors in place of potentiometer and how to calculate the value of resistor?

[MP2307 Data sheet](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/MP2307_r1.9.pdf)

Comment: Please link the data sheet for the MP2307.

Comment: The datasheet will explain how to calculate the resistor value, but if you have the unit in front of you why not just set the desired voltage, remove the pot, measure the resistance that gives the voltage?

Comment: It is straight-forward from the data sheet I have linked.

Comment: Here's a site to calculate feedback resistor values given the part's feedback or reference voltage.  You can put the low side resistor value in as "fixed" and it will tell you what to use for the high side and what the output voltage and tolerance will be:  http://www.syncbuck.com

Comment: Thanks all for replying, got it !!

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat I have one more Question: According to data sheet, I can put 10K-ohm for R2, 44.2 K-ohm for R1 and I will get 5 V output but I just want to know if I also need to change the value of Inductor because Inductor used in data sheet is  4uH and inductor used in mini 360 is 2uH. So changing resistors R1 and R2 will cause any effect on Inductor value ?

Comment: @Ashish1313 The feedback resistors have nothing to do with the inductor value. The switching frequency (fixed for this chip), maximum load current, output capacitor, and acceptable ripple are the main things that affect the choice of inductor (other than size and cost constraints, anyway); without information on any of those, we can't say why they used a different inductor here. I can *guess* that it's probably for cost reasons at the expense of worse output ripple, but I can't say for sure.

Comment: Cover the pot in hot glue, tadaa! Now it's a pair of fixed resistors

Answer (score 5):

What matters is the internal reference voltage inside the circuit. The data-sheet states a reference voltage of 0.925 V. Therefore, the resistive divider made of your potentiometer and the low-side resistance \$R_2\$ must be sized so that, in regulation, the voltage at pin 5 is 0.925 V.

You can either disconnect your potentiometer once you have the correct voltage and measure its resistance or calculate the resistance value with the below expression:

[image]

This is an approximate expression neglecting the bias current contribution from the feedback pin but if the current in the divider is strong enough, it is usually not an issue. The calculation is also given in the data-sheet, page 7.

Answer (score 2):

$$V_{FB} = V_{OUT}\  \frac {R_2}{R_1 + R_2} $$

Which means that:

$$R_1 = \left( \frac {V_{OUT}}{V_{FB}} - 1\right) \ R_2$$

So using the 8.2kΩ on the board with 5V output, you need to replace the potentiometer with 36.1kΩ (standard 2%) resistor.

Less parts to replace.